# removing items from List through JTable

Tags: jtable

I made TableModel that uses an ArrayList, I was trying to remove selected item from both table and List, I wanted it to delete all selected items, but I had exceptions thrown, so I tried to make it simple, I made this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
    purchases.remove(purchasesTable.convertRowIndexToModel(purchasesTable.getSelectedRow()));

    purchasesTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

But when I remove rows, even though it works as intended sometimes I get these exceptions:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:638)    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:414)   at
>   table.PurchasesTableModel.setValueAt(PurchasesTableModel.java:62)     at
>   javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(JTable.java:2743)   at
>   javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(JTable.java:4725)   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.fireEditingStopped(AbstractCellEditor.java:141)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$EditorDelegate.stopCellEditing(DefaultCellEditor.java:368)
>   ...

and I have no idea what can cause this

in my model in setValueAt I just do this:
`Purchase purchase = list.get(rowIndex);` so from what I understand this function gets incorrect index, but why? ;/

Well thank you all for help ;p I FOUND SOLUTION:
when I was deleting cell was still in editing mode, it was JComboBox

```
if (purchasesTable.isEditing()) purchasesTable.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();

purchasesTable.editingStopped(new ChangeEvent(purchasesTable));
```

both of these solutions worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that your index number is not an index in ArrayList.size(). A size() of 3 is 0 indexed and will have indexes [0, 1, 2]. An index of 3 is out of bounds.